# Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}, n>0$, defined by $x_n=\int_{1}^{n} \frac {\cos t} {t^2} dt$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}, n>0$, defined by $x_n=\int_{1}^{n} \frac {\cos t} {t^2} dt$
is convergent.
Try:
$|x_n|\le \int_{1}^{n} \frac {1} {t^2} dt=1-\frac 1n <1$
Hence the sequence is bounded above. Now I wish to show that the sequence is monotone increasing.
$x_{n+1}-x_n=\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac {\cos t} {t^2} dt>0$ since $\frac {\cos t} {t^2}>0$ in $t\in [n, n+1]$. Is my argument correct. I'm not very happy the way I described the 2nd part. Please tell me if I am wrong and show me the best way possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $n=3$, $t=\pi\in[3,4]$ is such that $(\cos t)/t^2<0$.

Comment: Your comparison idea will work better if you use it to show tht the sequence is _Cauchy_.

Comment: @Troposphere I got your point. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. It is enough to show that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
2. For $m>n$, we have $|x_m-x_n|=\left|\int_n^m\frac{\cos t}{t^2}dt\right|\le \int_n^m\left|\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\right|dt\le \int_n^m\frac{1}{t^2}dt$.